# Why does Select not work here?

Tags: functions, filtering, conditional

Why does this not work? It returns empty while I expect the first two elements are selected.

```
Select[{{x1, ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y1, 
   ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y1, 
   ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1]}}, #[[2]] == 
   ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5] &]
```

Also, how can I include the third element here?

```
Select[{{x1, ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y1, 
   ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y2, 
   ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1 && t <= 5]}, {y1, 
   ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1]}}, #[[2]] == 
   ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5] &]
```

Answer (score 5):

**Edit 3**

I am not explaining the logic again, as it is explained below, but this is much cleaner.

This is the second example

```
list = {{x1, ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y1, 
    ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y2, 
    ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1 && t <= 5]}, {y1, 
    ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1]}};
rule = {ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5] -> x, 
   ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1 && t <= 5] -> y};
invrule = Map[Reverse, rule];

Select[list /. rule, ContainsAny[Join[{x, y}]]] /. invrule
```

> [image: list]

**Edit 2**

In more complicated situations, where the rules do not combine nicely, you can create two separate ones, select them individually and join the list. Like so:

```
list = {{x1, ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y1, 
    ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y2, 
    ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1 && t <= 5]}, {y1, 
    ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1]}};
rule = {ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5] -> x, 
   ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1 && t <= 5] -> y};
invrule = Map[Reverse, rule];
```

then

```
Join[Select[list /. rule, #[[2]] == x &], 
  Select[list /. rule, #[[2]] == y &]] /. invrule
```

> [image: list]

**Edit 1**

You can use the following to invert the rule

```
list = {{x1, ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y1, 
    ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y1, 
    ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1]}};
rule = {ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5] -> x};
invrule = Map[Reverse, rule];
```

and then

```
Select[list /. rule, #[[2]] == x &] /. invrule
```

> [image: list]

And for the second example

list = {{x1, ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y1,
ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y2,
ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1 && t <= 5]}, {y1,
ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1]}};
rule = {ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5] -> x,
ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1 && t <= 5] -> x};
invrule = Map[Reverse, rule];

and then

```
Select[list /. rule, #[[2]] == x &] /. invrule
```

gives

> [image: Blockquote]

**Original**

@Nasser gave one way, here's another. Set the condition you want to pick to be `x` using a rule.

```
list = {{x1, ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y1, 
    ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]}, {y1, 
    ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1]}};
rule = ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5] -> x;
invrule = x -> ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5];
```

and then

```
Select[list /. rule, #[[2]] == x &] /. invrule
```

> [image: list]

Answer (score 4):

> while I expect the first two elements are selected.

Use `===` and not `==`

```
Select[{
  {x1, ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]},
  {y1, ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]},
  {y1, ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1]}},
 #[[2]] === ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

> how can I include the third element here?

Ok, I found why `Select` does not find `y2` for your second question. It is more subtle than I first thought it is.

To see why, it is due to the difference between `ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1 && t <= 5]` and `ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]`. We see the following

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That is why `Select` did not find the third entry. It is not the same!

Internally one is `Inequality` and the other is not. Hence did not select it. One workaround is to first change the `Inequality` like this and then call `Select`

```
expr = {{x1, ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]},
   {y1, ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5]},
   {y2, ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1 && t <= 5]},
   {y1, ConditionalExpression[1, t >= 1]}};
expr = expr /. Inequality[a_, LessEqual, b_, LessEqual, c_] :> a <= b <= c;
Select[expr, #[[2]] === ConditionalExpression[1, 1 <= t <= 5] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the main reason why it did not find the third entry before, is that under the cover `t >= 1 && t <= 5` is not the same as `1 <= t <= 5`